# pandas groupby conditional row sum

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   'col_2': [1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
                   'col_3':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      2      1     A
1      2      2     A
2      2      3     A
3      3      1     B
4      3      2     B
5      3      3     B
6      3      4     B
```

I want to sum `col_2` over rows with  `col_1 >= col_2`.

The desired output should be:

```
   col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4
0      2      1     A      3
1      2      2     A      3
2      2      3     A      3
3      3      1     B      6
4      3      2     B      6
5      3      3     B      6
6      3      4     B      6
```

I came to:

```
df.groupby(['col_3']).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['col_1'] >= x['col_2']]['col_2'].sum())
```

This works, however, will be extremely slow when data become large (millions of rows), is there any more efficient way?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I want the result to be at the group level, so it will be convenient for me to have the save value of col_4 within a group. But your comment does enlight in a sense that, for this specific task, I could simply drop observations that do not meet the criteria and count number of observations of each group, which I think may be much more time-saving than the current one. Anyway, it would be best to have a more efficient solution for this kind of task, in general. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

just do the conditional math ahead of time.

```
In [46]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
       :                    'col_2': [1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
       :                    'col_3':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})

In [47]: df['cond_val'] = (df.col_1 >= df.col_2) * df.col_2

In [48]: df
Out[48]:
   col_1  col_2 col_3  cond_val
0      2      1     A         1
1      2      2     A         2
2      2      3     A         0
3      3      1     B         1
4      3      2     B         2
5      3      3     B         3
6      3      4     B         0


In [50]: df.groupby('col_3').cond_val.sum()
Out[50]:
col_3
A    3
B    6
Name: cond_val, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This one comes out fastest in my timing tests (my attempt with using pre-selection and merging the sum series was twice as slow).